# Adding sudo to a find command: what does it change?

Tags: sudo

What is the difference between the output of this 2 commands

```
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
```

and

```
sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
```

?

Answer (score 4):

The commands are similar.  The `find` will add group write permissions to all *regular files* in  the directories `var`, `vendor`, `pub/static`, `pub/media`, and `app/etc` in the current directory.

The second command will execute the `find` command with escalated privileges (as root). This may be needed to change permissions on files with `chmod` if some of the files are owned by a user which is *not* your ordinary user (the user executing either command line) or if that user can't access all files in those directories or below due to access permissions on the directories.

Comment: won't the `-exec` option subprocess also be running as the root, so it would change permissions on files that the regular user may not have rights to at all

Comment: @ivanivan I believe this is what I meant by "This may be needed if some of the files are owned by a user which is not your ordinary user".

Answer (score 3):

See `man sudo`:

```
sudo, sudoedit — execute a command as another user
```

Because you don't specify a username for sudo in your example (i.e. `sudo -l anotheruser`) it runs the command as the *user* root by default.

So the difference is, that the first command is executed with the user permissions of the current terminal, the second command is executed with the permissions of the user *root*.

For more details see the man page of *sudo*.

Answer (score 1):

`find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;`

May not be allowed to lookup in some directories
You'll get exception: `find: ‘XXX’: Permission denied`
The second cmd uses `sudo` to extend lookup permissions

Comment: Thanks @palik. Yes, I am getting exception `find: ‘XXX’: Permission denied`. Why I am getting this exception ?

Comment: because lack of lack of lookup permissions. You have to use `sudo` if you allowed @ChristophS's answer